# How to calloc a 2D array without valgrind errors?

Tags: c, arrays, calloc

I am working on a school project, trying to create a 2d array based on variables.

```
int **wagner;
wagner = (int **)calloc((sizeofvstup1 + 1), sizeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < (sizeofvstup1 + 1); i++) {
    wagner[i] =(int *)calloc((sizeofvstup2 + 1), sizeof(int));
}
```

I use `calloc` to get 0 on every array place. But valgrind keeps telling me something like:

> Invalid write of size 8 at the "wagner[i]..."

`sizeofvstup1` and `sizeofvstup2` are variables of the length of the array.
How am I supposed to use `calloc` here? Tried many times to change the lines a bit but never helped... :/

What should the code look like to work properly?

Comment: In the first allocation, you probably want a pointer to an int for sizeof. Or rather, use `sizeof *wagner` (and in the second, `sizeof *wagner[i]`). Also, don't cast the return value of `calloc/malloc` when using C.

Comment: See [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) for the proper way to do this instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not allocating the proper amount of size for the first allocation:

```
wagner =(int **)calloc((sizeofvstup1+1),sizeof(int));
```

Here you're allocating space for an array of pointers, but you're passing `sizeof(int)` for the element size.  If an `int` is smaller than an `int *`, then you don't have enough space and you end up reading/writing past the end of the array.

Change the element size of the allocation to `sizeof(int *)`.  Also, don't cast the return value of `calloc`:

```
wagner = calloc((sizeofvstup1 + 1), sizeof(int *));
```

Comment: Oh, ok thank you, works from now, but different problem occured.. In my code after some algorithm I have:
podobnost=wagner[sizeofvstup1+1][sizeofvstup2+1];
And for this valgrind says:
Invalid read of size 8
==8770==    at 0x40144F: main (main.c:212)
==8770==  Address 0x55cb9e0 is 0 bytes after a block of size 48 alloc'd
 and
==8770== Invalid read of size 4
==8770==    at 0x40145F: main (main.c:212)
How to fix this problem?

Comment: @MartinIndrych That's a different problem, for which you should open a separate question.

Comment: can't ask anther question so early.. :/

Comment: @MartinIndrych Then ask when you're able.  :)

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned the code uses the wrong size for the 1st allocation.

To never having to think again which size to use when allocating there is simple trick:

Given that the result of a memory allocation is always assigned to a pointer just simply request to allocate (multiples of) the size this target pointer is pointing to by doing:

```
int **wagner;
wagner = calloc(sizeofvstup1 + 1, sizeof *wagner);
for (size_t = 0; i < (sizeofvstup1 + 1); ++i) {
    wagner[i] = calloc(sizeofvstup2 + 1, sizeof *wagner[i]);
}
```

<sup>*(all other changes to the code are unrelated to this "trick")*</sup>

This way the code would even survive a change from

```
int ** wagner;
```

to let's say

```
double ** wagner;
```

without *any* modifications.